# What is the best way to utilize Subversive when sharing multi-module project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2, m2eclipse, subversive

I'm trying to share multi-module Maven project (using m2eclipse plug-in) from SpringSource Tool Suite 2.0.0 to Subversion server (Subversive plug-in for Eclipse). I've found that svn:ignore property is not propagated to submodules of the parent project: I need to right-click on the property and run "Apply recursively...". More, it won't work if root folder of submodule is not in SVN repository yet: first of, I need to check-in root folder, then right-click on the property and run "Apply recursively...".

Am I missing something? Please, describe your way of ridding of the problem.

P.S. The project has nested structure:

```
PARENT
+ component A
  - module AA
  - module AB
+ component B
  - module BA
+ component C
  - module CA
  - module CB
  - module CC
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but What?

Comment: What part of the question is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Eclipse plugin 'Subversive' GUI is not advanced enouggh to support the kind of property setting you want, may be a command line would be more efficient.

```
cd PARENT
ls -s | xargs svn propset -R -F ignore.txt svn:ignore
```

That way, you apply `svn:ignore` only on already committed directories (and sub-directory) without having to commit first `PARENT`.

If you are on Windows, a package like [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) can help (or there is multiple alternative, like PowerShell)